# PHP include statment adding VARS at the end?

Tags: php, variables, include, var

I am trying to add some variables at the end of an "**include**". Is this possible?

Here is the code that DOES NOT WORK:

```
include('login.php?' . "message=used");
```

Comment: `$message='used';` defined before the include would be the appropriate way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to include a querystring. Includes/requires essentially put the included code in place. Just declare whatever variables the includes needs before you include the file:

```
$message = 'used';
include('login.php);
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's not, and you really have no reason to do so, you see. Every variable you define before the include will be available from the include.

```
$var = "Hello include";
include("login.php");
```

//Include.php

```
echo $var;
```

Will output "Hello include"

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the `include()` takes the parameter as a filename, so when you use `login.php?message=used` it's looking for `login.php?message=used.php`, which obviously doesn't exist.

You could alter the `.ini` file setting `allow_url_include` but this poses a potential security issue, but otherwise just declare your variables before including the file.